# Sending emails digitally signed with S/MIME encryption using phpmailer

Tags: php

I need to know that how can I send an email digitally signed with S/MIME encryption using the phpmailer API.
I'm able to send normal email. Please provide me with links or examples of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope that this will help you:

```
require "class.phpmailer.php";
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsMail();

$mail->AddAddress("email@example.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test 1";
$mail->Body = "Test 1 of PHPMailer.";

// CUSTOMISED SIGN EMAIL : START 
$mail->sign_cert_file="/xxx/key.pem"; 
$mail->sign_key_file="/xxx/key.pem"; 
$mail->sign_key_pass="yyy"; 
// CUSTOMISED SIGN EMAIL : END

$mail->Send(); // Send encrypted email!
```